# Creating a qt makefile from an existing visual studio project

Tags: linux, visual-studio, qt, makefile, qmake

I have a simple visual studio project that works.
I want to create a makefile for it on linux.
the project has 3 files (main.cpp, a.h, a.cpp)
i wrote a .pro file:

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (2.01a) ???�? 4. ??? 15:22:14 2012
######################################################################

TARGET = YetAnotherQtApp
CONFIG += qt
HEADERS += a.h
SOURCES += main.cpp a.cpp
```

I ran in the shell:

```
>>qmake -o Makefile YetAnotherQtApp.pro
```

works great.
it created for me a Makefile
but when i ran 'make' in the shell it does not compile at all.
it basically gives an error about every thing in the project (includes, variables etc')

what am i doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is an error occurs almost in each row? The problems maybe caused by the file format. Try to convert your source files from DOS format to UNIX format. `dos2unix` can help you do that. The exact error message will help a lot more.